# exception while trying to receive a file from server

Tags: android, sockets, exception

i run some code to connect to a server, send it an Object and then receive another Object.
while running this on my Android enulator (v2.2) i get - `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed`
the connection to the server is successful and i'm able to send the object but when i'm trying to do `socket.getInputStream()`  it throws the exception

this is my connector class:

```
public class ConnectionToServer {
    UserProblemRequest sentProblem;
    Problem responseProblem;
    Socket socket;

    public ConnectionToServer(){
        sentProblem = null;
        responseProblem = null;
        socket = null;
    }

    public void connect(){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting...");
            socket = new Socket(Utils.SERVER_IP, Utils.SERVER_PORT);
            Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS: Connected!");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR: Falied to connect! (UnknownHostException)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR: Falied to connect! (IOException)");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setProblemFromByteArray(byte[] data, boolean isFile){
        sentProblem = new UserProblemRequest();
        sentProblem.fileBArray = data.clone();
        if (isFile){
            sentProblem.requestType = Utils.requestType_IMAGE;
        }
        else {
            sentProblem.requestType = Utils.RequestType_STRING;
        }
    }

    public void sendProblem(){

        ObjectOutputStream os;

        try {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending file to server...");
            os.writeObject(sentProblem);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR: Falied to send file to server!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS: File sent to server!");
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to close socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Problem reciveResponseFromServer(){

        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            responseProblem = (Problem) ois.readObject();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseProblem;
    }

}
```

and i use this code to run it:

```
ConnectionToServer serverConnection = new ConnectionToServer();
serverConnection.connect();
serverConnection.setProblemFromByteArray(temp_data, true);
serverConnection.sendProblem();
Problem responseProblem = serverConnection.reciveResponseFromServer();
serverConnection.closeConnection();
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does closing the ObjectOutputStream() in sendProblem() wind up closing the underlying socket so that when you getInputStream() in reciveResponseFromServer() the socket is already closed?

Comment: i read up about it and yes! if you close the outputStream then the socket is closed.